# What is actually tuned during prompt engineering of autoregressive LLMs like GPT?

Tags: transformer, activation-functions, chatgpt, gpt

There are a lot of sites going over prompt engineering, but I don't see them explaining what is actually being changed. Is it hidden activation layers being tuned?